# datetime.date(TimeStamp).replace(day=01) gives an integer is required error

Tags: python, python-datetime

I have a timestamp column in my Db table (defined as datetime column)
and I try to make the day value as first of that month .

```
for (ObservationRawDataId, TimeStamp, TankSystemId, RawDeliveryLitres, ProductName, SiteCode) in cursor:
    print TimeStamp <----2019-06-21 00:00:00

     startdate = datetime.date(TimeStamp).replace(day=01)
```

But im getting following error;

```
 an integer is required
```

What Im doing wrong here?

Comment: `datetime.date()` takes `year, month, day` as parameters, not a string that looks like that. Maybe you’re looking for [`datetime.datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)?

Comment: @Ry- no I wnat to make the day value as first day of the month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the date string to date object using `datetime.strptime`. You can only work with datetime object here `startdate.replace(day=1)`

```
from datetime import datetime
startdate = datetime.strptime("2019-06-21 00:00:00","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").replace(day=1)
print(startdate)
```

Output:

```
2019-06-01 00:00:00
```

See this in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/BelovedInsubstantialChief)

Comment: @Ratha You can check whether the returned value is a python `datetime` object by using `print(type(TimeStamp))`.